# HP keyboard KB-0316 compatibility with MacBookPro

Tags: macos, laptop, keyboard, macbook-pro

I have 3 related questions:

1. Is an HP keyboard model number KB-0316 compatible with MacBookPro, OS X Version 10.5.8?
2. What is needed to connect the two, if they are compatible (the keyboard has a round purple plug that doesn't look like it would fit anywhere on the laptop)?
3. A mouse will be needed, correct? If so, does that plug into laptop, into the or keyboard (can find no openings on the keyboard for this)?

Answer (score 0):

1. The KB-0316 comes with a PS/2 connector--which is purple, as you noted, I believe--that should work provided you have a a PS/2 to USB adapter.

   [image: PS/2 to USB adapter]
   [image: Compact PS/2 to USB adapter, thanks Gerbal]
2. See point 1.
3. Needed? That depends entirely on whether or not you want one. Last time I checked, you could also use the touchpad that is on the MacBook Pro.
   *Should you want a mouse*, you might want to get one that uses USB, and not PS/2.

Comment: Really a PS/2 to USB adapter.
![pic](http://i.imgur.com/O4xNWpU.jpg)

Comment: @Gerbal In fairness, I see I've added a bad picture. I do mean a PS/2 to USB, though the picture I attached is USB to PS/2. I'll update that at least.